# Click button to show div, then remove button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have managed to create a button that shows my div. but I want to have the button disappear as that happens.

At the moment my button only disappears the second time I click it. Any help appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.click').click(function() {
    $('#contact-form').toggle('slide', 500)
    $('.click').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.click {
  display: block;
}

#contact-form {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click">click</button>
<div id="contact-form"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it is not working is, you are mixing the `display` between CSS and JavaScript. jQuery uses the current inline style to check if the button is hidden to display it, when you use `.toggle()`. Since it doesn't have anything at first, it adds a `display: block` (or whatever the initial value is) and then when you do the second time, it correctly identifies and removes.

The best thing to do is to use classes. I would suggest something like this parent class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.click').click(function() {
    $("body").toggleClass("contact-form-open");
  });
});
```

```css
.contact-form-open .click,
#contact-form {
  display: none;
}
.contact-form-open #contact-form {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click">Click Me</button>
<div id="contact-form">
  Contact Form
</div>
```

This way, you control everything using CSS and you don't mess up with the event listeners or add the yucky inline CSS.

Answer (score 0):

> but I want to have the button disappear as that happens.

So just use `hide()` instead of `toggle` :

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    $('.click').hide();
    $('#contact-form').toggle('slide', 500) 
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.click').click(function() {
    $('.click').hide();
    $('#contact-form').toggle('slide', 500) 
  });
});
```

```css
#contact-form {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click">click</button>
<div id="contact-form">Form content</div>
```

Comment: The same in your snippet.. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326126/error-while-calling-jquery-show-in-stack-overflow-snippet

Answer (score 0):

I've tried what you've tried and it seems to be working. Maybe it's because you don't close the div tag ?

```
$(function() {

  $('.click').click(function() {
    $('.myDiv').toggle();
    $('.click').toggle();
  })

});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/wD0bwf8XK3CFXXM7rVWF?p=preview

Comment: No. Read my answer. That's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

More easy:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.click').click(function() {
        $("#contact-form").show();
        $(this).remove();
      });
    });
```

```css
#contact-form{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button class="click">Click Me</button>
    <div id="contact-form">
      Contact Form
    </div>
```